# samba share inaccessible / you don't have permissions

Tags: linux, samba, active-directory, shared-folders

I have setup a samba share folder, however, when I try to access the share, I am getting "`Windows Can not access the \\server\share1. You don't have permissions to access \\server\share1`"

This server is joined to AD and I am able to list the shares using `smbclient` and AD User credentials. I don't know what I am missing. Strange thing is that the Share1 does not even prompt to enter different credentials, however pops up the access denied message.

```
[root@samba]# smbclient -L samba -U username
Enter user's password:
Domain=[EXAMPLE] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.23-35.el6_8]

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        share1          Disk      Test Share
```

Here is the smb.conf:

```
        workgroup = EXAMPLEDOMAIN
        ;password server = ad-cxxac.example.com
        realm = EXAMPLE.COM
        security = ads
        ;idmap uid = 10000-20000
        ;idmap gid = 10000-20000
        template shell = /bin/sh
        winbind use default domain = true
        winbind offline logon = true
        winbind refresh tickets = yes
        log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
        debug level = 3
        netbios name = samba
        encrypt passwords = yes
        winbind enum groups = no
        winbind enum users = no
        debuglevel = 3

#============================ Share Definitions ==============================
[share1]
        comment = Test Share
        path = /share1
        valid users =  EXAMPLE\username
        force group = "Domain Users"
        writable = yes
        read only = no
        force create mode = 0660
        create mask = 0777
        directory mask = 0777
        force directory mode = 0777
```

Domain Join is OK as well

```
[root@samba]# net ads testjoin
Join is OK
```

Directory permissions on the Shared Folder are

```
drwxrwxrwx.    2 root   domain users  4096 Sep  share1
```

Comment: I gotta ask, what are the directory permissions on `/share1`? (`ls -ld /share1/`)

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention in the orginal question, i switched them to 0777, but didn't work. `drwxrwxrwx.    2 root   domain users  4096 Sep share1`

Comment: What does `/var/log/samba/samba.log` say when you try to connect? It should say why it blocked the connection. Are you running a firewall? Can you mount it on `localhost`?

Comment: `[2017/09/19 11:11:05.824193,  2] smbd/sesssetup.c:1293(setup_new_vc_session)
  setup_new_vc_session: New VC == 0, if NT4.x compatible we would close all old resources.
[2017/09/19 11:11:05.843859,  1] smbd/service.c:1114(make_connection_snum)
  10.24.1.20 (10.24.1.20) connect to service share1 initially as user DOMAIN\gsingh (uid=10xx0, gid=1x0x0) (pid 507)`